# PyCharm not pulling docstrings from imports correctly

Tags: python, import, pycharm, python-import, docstring

I'm currently adding docstrings to a project so that I can leverage the [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation) feature in PyCharm. My project looks something like:

```
script\
    main.py
    HelperClasses/
        Helper.py
        ...
    OtherClasses/
        CustomClass1.py
        CustomClass2.py
        ...
```

`main.py` imports all of the files within `OtherClasses` and leverages them for various functionality and `OtherClasses` in turn import some of the `HelperClasses` and leverage their functionality. They look something like:

**main.py**

```
from OtherClasses import CustomClass1
from OtherClasses import CustomClass2

...
```

**CustomClass1.py**

```
from HelperClasses import Helper
...
```

**Helper.py**

```
def someFunction(x, y, z):
    """
    Does something with x, y and z.
    :param x: X value
    :param y: Y value
    :param z: Z value
    :return: Some other value
    """
    return doSomething(x, y, z)

...
```

My issue is that when attempting to use the [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation) feature while adding code to `CustomClass1.py` PyCharm failures to find the `Helper.py` file and index it properly to enable the docstrings to be found. Hence, I cannot use the [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation) feature in order to find docstring of `someFuncion`.

I believe this is because from `CustomClass1.py` the correct import would be `from ..HelperClasses import Helper` however as this script is imported from `main.py` the import needs to be from the context of `main.py`.

Futhermore, when I use the `from ..HelperClasses import Helper` it is indexed properly, however when `main.py` is ran, a error is thrown:

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Hence, is there any way to keep the docstrings working, while also having valid imports in this example?

Comment: A workaround of having imports behind `if False` statements works, although isn't very clean.